# Stylzed glass material WITH transmission using isometric camera and stacked panes (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, glass, reflection

I got a client who wants stacked glass panes with a transmissive material looking like this:
[image: mood1]
[image: mood2]

And I'm really struggling with getting the material right.
The closest I got was using two materials, one for the front of the panes and one for the front and back.
The colors are reflections of an abstract HDRI used.

[image: my material rendered]

It's the closest I got so far and still really far away.

The node setups I'm using for the materials are:

This material for the sides:
[image: side material]

And this material for front / back:
[image: front back material]

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the deadline is closing in.

I'm using Cycles for a proper transmission, but of course would have no problem switching to Eevee if someone knows a clever way.

You can find the .blend file here: [image]